# Find partial sums formula of series: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{1\cdot3\cdot5\cdot...\cdot(2n+1)}$

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{1\cdot3\cdot5\cdot...\cdot(2n+1)}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$$
For $n>1$: $$a_n=\frac{1}{2}(\frac{(2n+1)-1}{1\cdot3\cdot5\cdot...\cdot(2n+1)})\\=\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{3\cdot5\cdot...\cdot(2n-1)}-\frac{1}{3\cdot5\cdot...\cdot(2n+1)})$$
and $a_1=\frac1{3}$, hence
$$S_n=\frac1{3}+\frac1{2}(\frac1{3}-\frac1{3\cdot5\cdot\cdot...\cdot(2n+1)}).$$
I'm not sure why is there $\frac1{3}$inside the bracket and would be glad if someone clarified it.
(copied from a workbook)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a [telescoping series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series).

Let $u_n=\frac{1}{3\cdot5\cdots(2n+1)}$, then $u_1=\frac13$, $a_n=\frac12(u_{n-1}-u_n)$ and

$$S_2=a_1+a_2=a_1+\frac12(u_1-u_2)$$

$$S_3=a_1+a_2+a_3=a_1+\frac12(u_1-u_2+u_2-u_3)=a_1+\frac12(u_1-u_3)$$

$$S_n=a_1+\frac12(u_1-u_2+u_2-\dots+u_{n-1}-u_n)=a_1+\frac12(u_1-u_n)$$

You can also prove this by induction.

Answer (score 1):

Simpliy from OP's 3rd step:
$$A_k=\frac{1}{2}[B_k-B_{k+1}],~~ B_k=\frac{1}{1.3.5.7....(2k-1)}$$
By telescopic summation we get
$$S_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n} A_k= \frac{1}{2}[B_1-B_{n+1}]=\frac{1}{2}\left[ 1-\frac{1}{1.3.5.7....(2n+1)}\right]$$
So $$S_{\infty}=\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have corrected it now.